# Corrected road model to conform to earth curvature

Tags: blender

I have a 3D road model created in Blender, with a total length of less than 30km. I want to place this model into a 3D Earth system for presentation. However, I noticed that after placing it into the 3D Earth system, the model does not bend with the curvature of the Earth, resulting in an incorrect representation (some parts of the model may be submerged under the surface or floating in the air), as shown in the image.

[image]

How can I make adjustments in Blender to ensure that my road model conforms to the curvature of the Earth?
[part of road model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mUsIDdljNJRJsKHrG_aDo4i-n6sSRW2J/view?usp=sharing)